# What can be done with extremely, extremely persistent spammers?

Tags: feature-request, spam

There’s a really really active spam operation advertising apparently abortion pills and drugs in Indonesian.

It's extremely frequent; there are [54 hits on MetaSmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&body=aborsi) for "aborsi" in the post body. [There are 52 for "cytotec"](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&body=cytotec), which frequently appears. There are [102 true positives](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&body=jual) to 11 false for "jual", which means sell according to Google Translate, another term frequently in the spam.

**Can something be done about this?** Maybe an IP block or some sort of keyword ban to stop these posts? I am posting here so that the staff will see—something really should be done.

If something like this is to happen again, what should we do?

Comment: I don't speak indonesian but in malay (quite related language) jual means sell. Actually clicking on the link, the phrase "jual obat" is presumably "sell(ing) drugs" (its like "jual ubat" in malay)

Comment: Flagging it is good enough - flagging should feed spamram, which should stop stuff from hitting the site and SD at all.

Comment: @Calvin you’re right—they were spamming obat, which means drug. It was late and I was tired when writing this :P

Comment: SO/SE could integrate Smokey into the code base.  Why they haven't yet IDK.  Smokey is awesome and does so much good.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332633/beyond-flagging-it-what-can-i-do-to-stop-spam

Comment: That's not particularly persistent or egregious compared to the top spam gangs we see month after month.

Answer (score 6):

From the [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335633/extremely-extremely-persistent-spammers-selling-some-abortion-drug-related-thin#comment1105606_335633):

> Flagging it is good enough - flagging should feed spamram, which should stop stuff from hitting the site and SD at all. – Journeyman Geek